# nginx update on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu installs nginx 1.4.6 as default. I'm trying to install the lastest stable version of nginx 
I have tried add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx

it shows me error
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:nginx/'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

I have tried add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
and it shows me nothing

then I removed nginx and tried installing it again with sudo apt-get remove nginx but that also did not work out for me

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got this one figured out the thing is that I removed nginx and then added new ppa and then I ran **apt-get update** and **apt-get install** https://leftshift.io/upgrading-nginx-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-servers did the job for me

Comment: Hi ShaswatWayne , please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).